# Terraform - Cyclic dependency issue on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am provisioning multiple resources on GCP including a Cloud SQL (Postgres) DB and one VM instance. I am struggling with a cyclic dependency on Terraform during `terraform apply` as:

- Cloud SQL (Postgres) needs the IP of the VM for IP whitelisting
- The VM uses a start-up script that requires the Public IP of the Postgres DB

Hence, the cyclic dependency... Do you have any suggestion to tackle this in Terraform?

**File that creates the GCP VM (includes a startup script that requires the IP of the Postgres DB)**

```
data "template_file" "startup_script_airbyte" {
  template = file("${path.module}/sh_scripts/airbyte.sh")
  vars = {
    db_public_ip = "${google_sql_database_instance.postgres.public_ip_address}"
    db_name_prefix = "${var.db_name}"
    db_user = "${var.db_user}"
    db_password = "${var.db_password}"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "airbyte_instance" {
  name                    = "${google_project.data_project.project_id}-airbyte"
  machine_type            = local.airbyte_machine_type
  project                 = google_project.data_project.project_id
  metadata_startup_script = data.template_file.startup_script_airbyte.rendered #file("./sh_scripts/airbyte.sh")
  allow_stopping_for_update = true

  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.data_project_services,
  ]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "ubuntu-2004-focal-v20210415"
      size  = 50
      type  = "pd-balanced"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {
      network_tier = "PREMIUM"
    }
  }

  service_account {
    email  = google_service_account.airbyte_sa.email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
}
```

**Script that creates the Postgres DB (requires IP of the VM above)**

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "postgres" {
  name = "postgres-instance-${random_id.db_name_suffix.hex}"
  project = google_project.data_project.project_id
  database_version = "POSTGRES_13"
  settings{
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
    backup_configuration {
      enabled = true
      start_time = "02:00"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "cloudsql.iam_authentication"
      value = "on"
    }

    database_flags {
      name  = "max_connections"
      value = 30000
    }
    
    #Whitelisting the IPs of the GCE VMs in Postgres
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled = "true"
      authorized_networks {
        name = "${google_compute_instance.airbyte_instance.name}"
        value = "${google_compute_instance.airbyte_instance.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a gcp expert by any stretch, but one would hope you could build the instance in a subnet, and whitelist the subnet cidr in the db. That way you wouldn't need to know the precise ip of the vm, just the subnet cidr.

Comment: Thank you. Very good idea. I ended up using a static public IP as shared below, but will keep the option in mind for the future

Answer (score 1):

One way to overcome this would be to get [static public IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#gcloud_1), using [google_compute_address](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_address). You do this before you create your instance, and then attach it to the instance.

This way the IP can be whitelisted in Cloud SQL, before the instance is created.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this solved my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to install the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy in the VM. Then you do not need to whitelist IP addresses. This will remove the cyclic dependency.